# How do I change the appearance of every tab in the Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {   
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)
}
```

I put this in one of my tab's view controllers. However, this only sets that specific view. I copy and pasted this to all the other controllers, but it only sets when I tap on them. (If I don't tap on them, `viewDidLoad` doesn't run.)

I want all the tabs to show this image inset immediately when all the tabs are shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to loop through all of the controllers for the tab bar. Put this code either after your `UITabBarController` initialization (and its `viewControllers` are populated), or in your first view controller's `viewDidLoad` (It only needs to be run *once*).

```
// Loop through ALL the controllers in the TabBarController and set their tab bar item imageInsets.
for (index, controller) in enumerate(tabBarController.viewControllers) {
    controller.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)
}
```